# PHP / x64 Windows Core Error 16 / E_CORE_ERROR

Tags: php, php7

Using [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) on Windows x64 with both versions 7.2.6 and 7.3.10 of PHP on my local development machine I'm receiving a vague `E_CORE_ERROR` in certain situations. The `error_get_last()` function returns nothing. According to [PHP's Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/errorfunc.constants) this is generated by PHP itself, not my code (apparently). I upgraded to the latest stable build and the error persists. Is this an issue I can/should report to the PHP development team or is there a chance that there is an issue with my code and the error handler is simply not properly reporting the issue? I was completely unaware that there was an issue until I profiled using Xdebug.

Comment: Surely you have more details than just `E_CORE_ERROR`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Is there another way to determine errors besides `E_CORE_ERROR` and `error_get_last()`? If so please share, I'd love to have this issue resolved.